# While loop on Python class attribute

Tags: python, class, while-loop

The 'while' doesn't 'break' when
self.text is set to '' by the kill function.

Can someone help me make this work or suggest a better way? 
Need to run a string through 10+ functions quitting if string becomes ''
Returning inside each function seems redundant.

```
class Class(object):
    def run(self, text):
        self.text = text

        while self.text:
            self.nothing1()
            self.kill()
            self.nothing2()
            return self.text # stop if all functions run

    def nothing1(self):
        print 'nothing1'
        self.text = self.text

    def kill(self):
        print 'kill'
        self.text = ''

    def nothing2(self):
        print 'nothing2'
        self.text = self.text

C = Class()
C.run('some string')
```

**Clarification:**
Goal is to run a string through a many functions in order just once stopping if any one of the functions sets the string to "", i obviously misunderstand how 'while' work, it seems the cleanest way to me.

Comment: This code does actually break on the first iteration.

Comment: Correct, can someone clarify why it doesn't break at' kill'?

Comment: @mark Why should it stop after `kill`? There is not break statement. So it executes the rest of the functions bellow `kill`. But the next iteration of `while` doesn't go because the condition `self.nect==True` is not met.

Comment: +1 While loops may have been misunderstood, but the problem that needs solving is interesting and common.  It is clear from the question, too.

Answer (score 4):

Update 2: If your goal is to run a string through several functions, then your design is essentially all wrong.

Each function should NOT set a member, but instead accept a string, and return a string. Your loop should then test whether or not the value is good:

```
currstr = 'foo'
for f in (self.nothing1, self.kill, self.nothing2):
    tmpstr = f(currstr)
    if not tmpstr: break # or return, or raise exception
    currstr = tmpstr
```

---

Update: Apparently your problem is that you don't like how while loops work. While loops only break when execution hits the test - that is, once execution enters the body, absent a break or exception, it will continue to the end of the block, and only then will the test be re-evaluated.

Probably the cleanest way to do this is to wrap `self.text` with a [property](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property).

You then have three reasonable choices for the logic in your property function:

1. You can create a system of handlers that are called when the property is changed, and do whatever you like there (including the logic of one the next two options);
2. Include a specific test for an empty string, and raise an exception on that, and handle it outside of the loop; or
3. Raise an exception on every single alteration, and handle it inside your loop.

You also have another option, which is to raise an exception in `kill` in much the same way as outlined above.

---

Your code works perfectly for me:

```
In [139]: cpaste
Pasting code; enter '--' alone on the line to stop or use Ctrl-D.
:class Class(object):
:    def run(self, text):
:        self.text = text
:
:        while self.text:
:            self.nothing1()
:            self.kill()
:            self.nothing2()
:
:    def nothing1(self):
:        print 'nothing1'
:        self.text = self.text
:
:    def kill(self):
:        print 'kill'
:        self.text = ''
:
:    def nothing2(self):
:        print 'nothing2'
:        self.text = self.text
:
:C = Class()
:C.run('some string')
:--
nothing1
kill
nothing2
```

Comment: As I got it, any function may set the `text` to `''`. But I may be wrong.

Comment: Idea is to stop at kill and not to run nothing2

Comment: @mark I got it this way: any function may behave as `kill` by setting `text=''`. Otherwise it would be easier to add `if` condition with `break` after `self.kill()`.

Comment: Thanks Marcin, i understand my mistake now.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a checking of `text` being `''` after each function executing:

```
class Class(object):
    def run(self, text):
        self.text = text

        func_to_exec = [self.nothing1,self.kill,self.nothing2]
        while True:
            for func in func_to_exec:
                func()
                if not self.text:
                    break
            else:
                continue #executed only if no 'break' was met (starts the next iteration of `while` loop)
            break #get out of the 'while True' loop


    def nothing1(self):
        print 'nothing1'
        self.text = self.text

    def kill(self):
        print 'kill'
        self.text = ''

    def nothing2(self):
        print 'nothing2'
        self.text = self.text
```

Output:

```
>>> C.run('some string')
nothing1
kill
```

Comment: Thanks! Cleanest by far, however i don't think the 'while' is needed at all, it should break out of the 'for'

Comment: @mark Hm. As I got all those functions must be executed in an infinite loop untill one of them returns `''`. No?

Comment: My bad, i forgot to included 'return self.text' at the bottom of the 'while'

Answer (score 1):

While it may seem redundant, you *can* shorten the loop if you return the string in each function.  It's a more functional approach to the problem, using lazy evaluation:

```
def run(self, text):
        self.text = text

        func_to_exec = [self.nothing1, self.kill, self.nothing2]
        all(func() for func in func_to_exec) # generator will evaluate func lazily
```

Nice and clear with a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Write a decorator that raises StopIteration if the attribute becomes ''.

Comment: Does that mean a @decorator above each of the 10 functions? Not 100% on decorators but the idea is to not include redundant code in each function.

Comment: Either that, or wrap each of the calls in the decorator. Or you could do some \_\_getattr\_\_ magic, but you probably don't want to.